# How to add plain functions (not class's method) in Magento 2 Module?

Tags: magento2

I want to add plain functions that I can use instead of static methods from classes. What is the best way to add this?

Answer (score 0):

You can include the PHP functions in `app/bootstrap.php`.
See how the `__()` function has been imported from `app/functions.php` in bootstrap file.

Answer (score 0):

By nature magento doesn't give you a way to do this. Thats where helper classes come in.

You can obvious add global functions into the `app/functions.php` that's where the `__()` translation function sits, but **this is not good practice** for obvious reasons.